# Tkinter Frame adding itself to main window

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have a program that is suppose to create a new Toplevel widget and then add a frame to it. Both the toplevel and frame classes are already created separately so when they are called my window fills automatically. But when the button is clicked the Toplevel window pops up but the frame adds itself to the main window and not the new Toplevel

Main window code

> class MainWindow(Tkinter.Tk):

```
def __init__(self,version):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)  # creates the main window
    self.title('Awana Control ' + version) # names the main window

    topframe = Tkinter.Frame(self)
    topframe.grid(column=0,row=0)

    openNewFamilyWindowButton = Tkinter.Button(topframe, text='Add a new family',command=partial(newWindow,'NewFamilyWindow'))
    openNewFamilyWindowButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #openEditStudentWindowButton = Tkinter.Button(topframe, text='edit current repository', command=partial(newWindow,'studentFinderWindow'))
    #openEditStudentWindowButton.grid(row=0, column=1)

    openTotalsWindowButton = Tkinter.Button(topframe, text='Total Shipping Orders', command=partial(newWindow,'totalsWindow'))
    openTotalsWindowButton.grid(row=0, column=1)

    openTotalsWindowButton = Tkinter.Button(topframe, text='Lists By Grade', command=partial(newWindow,'gradeList'))
    openTotalsWindowButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

    #bottomframe = Tkinter.Frame(self)
    #bottomframe.grid(column=0,row=1)
```

> right here is when it adds the student
>   finder window class to the main
>   window. This class is responsible for
>   opening the new toplevel windows

```
    StudentFinderWindow().grid(column=0,row=1)


    self.mainloop()
```

here is the StudentFinderWindow class

> class StudentFinderWindow(Tkinter.Frame):

```
def __init__(self):
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self) # Create Window

    ##### window attributes
    #self.title('Edit Families') #sets window title

    ##### puts stuff into the window

    # text
    editStudentInfoLabel = Tkinter.Label(self,text='Select the family from the list below or search for one in the search box provided')
    editStudentInfoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # entry box
    self.searchRepositoryEntry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.searchRepositoryEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)

    # list box
    self.searchResults = Tkinter.Listbox(self,selectmode='SINGLE')
    self.searchResults.grid(row=2, column=0)

    # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
    #yscroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self, command=self.searchResults.yview, orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL)
    #yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S)
    #self.searchResults.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    # search results initial updater
    self.getStudentList()
    for student in self.studentList:
        self.searchResults.insert(Tkinter.END, student)

    ##### event handler 
    self.searchResults.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.editStudentWindowInit )
    self.searchRepositoryEntry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.updateSearch)

def updateSearch(self, event):
    parameters = self.searchRepositoryEntry.get()
    parameters = parameters.lower()
    length = len(parameters)
    self.searchResults.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
    for i in self.studentList:
        if i[0:length].lower() == parameters:
            self.searchResults.insert(Tkinter.END, i)


def getStudentList(self):
    global fileDirectory # gets the directory that all the files are in
    fileList = os.listdir(fileDirectory) # makes a list of files from the directory
    self.studentList = [] #  makes a new list
    for file in fileList: # for loop that adds each item from the file list to the student list
        if file[-3:] == 'txt':
            self.studentList.append(file[:-4])
```

> This is the function that opens the new window which is suppose to fill itself with a frame

```
def editStudentWindowInit(self,mevent):
    index = self.searchResults.curselection()
    student = self.searchResults.get(index)
    editStudentWindow = EditStudentWindow(student)
```

Here is the class that is opened

```
class EditStudentWindow(Tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,student):

        Tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title('Edit Family Info')

        Tkinter.Button(self,text='Edit Info',command=partial(self.fillInfo,student)).grid(column=0,row=0)
        Tkinter.Button(self,text='Edit Orders',command=partial(self.fillOrder,student)).grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.fillInfo(student)

    def fillInfo(self,student):

        try:
            self.order.grid_forget()
        except:
            pass
        self.info = EditFamilyWindow(student)
        self.info.grid(column=0,row=1)

    def fillOrder(self,student):
        try:
            self.info.grid_forget()
        except:
            pass
        self.order = EditShippingWindow(student)
        self.order.grid(column=0,row=1)
```

and here is the **init** of the frame class

```
class EditFamilyWindow(Tkinter.Frame):

def __init__(self,student):

    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is, your frame must be created as a descendant of a specific toplevel. You can't reparent a frame from one toplevel to another. So, for your code to work you must create the toplevel first, and then create your frame and tell it which toplevel to be created in.

Comment: But I created the toplevel in the editstudentwindow class. Then from there I added the frames to that toplevel. Or at least I thought I did

Comment: @Brandon: You say that the frame is showing up in the wrong toplevel. That can't happen by accident, your code is putting it there. This should be trivial to track down -- put a print statement where the frame is created and see what its toplevel window is.

Comment: The editstudentwindow class creates a toplevel as itself and then the frame and then places it inside of itself with the .grid but the frame appears in the main window for some reason not a different toplevel